# How to update redux store when calling a push method

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I am using FieldArray , my requirement is add upto 3 elements and I am using push method for this. I have a redux variable/property to check whether elements have reached upto 3.But how I can achieve that store variable change when I do push an element(pushing an element into array should increase that property value.

```
 {fields.map((doc, index) => (
                            <div>
                                <h4>Element #{index + 1}</h4>
                                <br/>
                                <div className="row">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp; {fields.length < 3 &&
                                        <button type="button"  className="btn btn-primary" onClick= 
                                        {() => fields.push({})}>
                                            Add Element
                                        </button>
                              </div>
                       </div>))}
```

Any pointers will be helpful, Thank you.

Comment: `.push` mutates the array. React and Redux work with immutable data, so when you do mutate the array, Redux doesn't know, so React doesn't know, so it doesn't get re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to update redux store is to dispatch actions. Here, when you click on your button, you just execute a function that updates your current fields array.

Second point, when working on React and Redux, you need to modify your state immutably, without changing it, by passing a new object. For example :

```
state = {
  cars: []
}

const newState = {
  ...state,
  cars: ['Ferrari']
}
```

Comment: Hello Dan, with Emile's input ..I have removed push method to add the element in FieldArray and used redux way to dispatch the action. Now I can see , in store I have added elements in FieldArray but they are not showing up on screen. Please check this,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446531/how-to-update-fieldarray-elements-with-redux-store-variable .  I have posted a new question regarding this, if you can provide any input on FieldArray that would be helpful. Thank you.