# how to update FieldArray elements with redux store variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, redux

- I am using redux-form with a FieldArray.By default 1 element will be there in array and it is populated from JSON. I can add upto 3
  elements in FieldArray component.
- In below code, 'elementList'
  property is coming from JSON and also I have store variables named
  as'elements' and 'elementList'. I initialize these store variable with elementList
  from JSON at first and then keep updating store variables when 'Add
  Element' is clicked on. I can see store variables are updating
  properly but on screen Field array elements are not updating.It may be because name property 'elementList' in FieldArray may refer to
  JSON element.

  Is it possible, if I can refer to store variables 'elementList' or 'elements' in name property
  of 'FieldArray'. Please advice.

Main page

```
  <div>
      <FieldArray name="elementList" component={Elements}
                  props={this.props}/>
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={event => this.addElement(elementDTO)}>Add Element
      </button>
      <br/>
  </div>
  
  addElement(elementDTO){
        if(this.props.elements && this.props.elements!=undefined && this.props.elements.length >= 3){
            return;
        }
        this.props.addReqElement(this.props.elements);
    }
```

Field Array page

```
const elements= ({props, meta: {error, submitFailed}}) => {
    const {fields} = props;
    return (
    {fields.map((element, index) => (
     <div> 
            //Field definitions
     </div>
))}
```

Thank you

Update:
Adding method from Redux Action and Reducer

```
 export function addReqElement(childList) {
         let state = store.getState()
         let newChild= 
            state.requestReducer.DTOobj.requestDoc;  //this is an empty element coming from backend with few properties and adding rest of the //proerties as below to create a new child 
        newChild.prop1 = null
        newChild.prop2 = null
        childList.push(newChild)
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch(setDoc(childList));
        }
    }
    

export function setDoc(payload) {
    return {
        type: ADD_DOC,
        payload: payload
    }
}
```

Update 2: I tried to remove push and used spread operator , but it did not work. I have inner array also, that is working as I am using different strategy. I take pull parent array ,it's index and update parent array with the new inner array. It works but parent array I am not getting how should I make it work. I tried to set the main array to the form props and render full page by dispatching an action but it did not work. Any suggestions plz?

From the main array page:

```
render() {
   const {fields, parentArrayFromStore} = this.props;
    return (
       <div className="col-sm-12">
          {fields.map((doc, index) => (
           <div key={index}>
            <div className="col-sm-12">
              <FieldArray name={`${doc}.innerArrayList`} component={CustomInnerArrayComponent}/>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
               <div className="col-sm-4">
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary"
                          onClick={event => this.addInnerArray(index, parentArrayFromStore ,fields.get(index).innerArrayList)}>Add Printer
                   </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ))}
    </div>)
            }
```

In Action class

```
export function addInnerArray(index, parentArrayFromStore, innerArrayList) {
    let newInnerItem= {};
    newInnerItem.prop1 = null
    newInnerItem.prop2 = null
   
    innerArrayList.push(newInnerItem)
    parentArrayFromStore[index].innerArrayList = innerArrayList;

    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(setParentArray(parentArrayFromStore));
    }
}

export function setParentArray(payload) {
    return {
        type: ADD_DOC,
        payload: payload
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you append the new-element in `elementList`, or save a copy of `elementList` and then append in that? Also, please add a working example in codesandbox / stackblitz.

Comment: Hello Rahul, I tried to create a new list and append both the existing list and the new child but it did not work out. Can you please provide some sample. I am new to UI development so need to check on putting that code alone on sandbox

Comment: Hi @Khushi can you please update your question with the statements used in this fn "addReqElement";
I would suggest that in mainpage constructor have a state with takes array as input and in "addReqElement" update that state using setstate,, don't mutate the state array using push/splice etc

Answer (score 1):

Hi the issue is with the push statement in your function when updating states in the constructor or reducer use concat or spread operator[...]>
I have made a sample over [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ashish0019/3487g2ax/)
please check

```
onAddItem() {
        let list = [...this.state.items, {text:`Check 1`}];
        this.setState({items:list});
}
```

in your case you can do the following

```
let arr = [...childList, newChild]
```

then dispatch the arr

```
 dispatch(setDoc(arr));
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have already tried using spread operator but it failed to work. FYI, I have one more array inside this array. That is working fine because I am getting the full parent array and index of the parent and pushing new child element in child array. I have updated question with update 2 , I do not how to update parent array in similar way, I even try to get the new parent array list and set it to main form and dispatched the action for full form but I am not getting any success with this :( Thank you for your effort

Comment: in that case can you share your reducer as well